# How to programmatically update references in sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have 2 templates: ArticleItem and ArticlePageItem, the ArticlePageItem has a ReferenceField 'Content.Reference' that links to an ArticleItem. Below is the code to create an article:

```
Item articlePageItem = articlePageParentItem.Add(articleItem.Name, new TemplateItem(master.GetItem(ConstantString.ArticlePageTemplateID)));
using (new UserSwitcher(Sitecore.Context.User))
{
    articlePageItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
    articlePageItem.Fields["Content.Reference"].Value = articleItem.ID.ToString();
    articlePageItem.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

But after I execute the code above, I cannot get the ArticleItem reference through `Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferences(articlePageItem)`, even though I use `Globals.LinkDatabase.UpdateReference(articlePageItem)`.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

**[Update]**
Below is our environment:
We have a website based on Sitecore, and we're developing another system aims to simplify the article management. We use .NET 4 & ASP.NET MVC 3 to implement this system, and reference Sitecore.Kernal.dll & Sitecore.Client.dll to our project. But our sitecore version is 6.2 which is incomplatible with .NET 4, so I just copied part of the configurations. I think it maybe dues to the incomplete web.config.

Comment: Are you calling `UpdateReferences` & `GetReferences` immediately after your code to create & link the items? (As this should work) Are you trying to Update/Get references within the same database (assuming `master`) or are you creating the item in `master` and trying to `GetReferences` in `web`? Any there any  configuration, or code, changes to the Sitecore system (pipelines, etc...)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I did the Create & Get operations in the same database(master).

Comment: Hi @SeanKearney, are there any other configurations related to the link database except `<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.SetGlobals, Sitecore.Kernel" />`?

Comment: Can you verify that if you create and link the item manually (within the content editor) that the `GetReferences` method works?

Comment: Is Content.Reference a valid field name?  I didn't think you could use a '.' character in a field name?

Comment: Hi @SeanKearney, yes, it works correctly if I use the content editor to create and link the item. I think it's probably related to the Save operation in Content Editor.

Comment: Hi @Bryan, the '.' character is valid in a field name, it was used in many places in our system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are executing the above code you should also consider publishing the item changes.

This can be done by using the following code snippet:

```
// publish all changed content
Database webDatabase = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
PublishOptions publishOptions = new PublishOptions(masterDatabase, webDatabase, PublishMode.Smart, Sitecore.Context.Language, DateTime.Now);

publishOptions.RootItem = vacatureRoot;

publishOptions.Deep = true;
Publisher publisher = new Publisher(publishOptions);
publisher.Publish();
```

Where 'vacatureRoot' is the root -> in your case articlePageParentItem
After publishing the references should be set automatically and should be retrievable by using the normal way of getting Fields.

It looks like you are using a ReferenceField and therefore your code should look something like this:

```
ReferenceField rfRef = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Content.Reference"];

if(rfRef != null && rfRef.TargetItem != null) 
{
 //Your logic here
}
```

Answer for comment:

I think you could best use the following code fragment ->

```
Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.UpdateReferences(articlePageItem);
```

I think this will do what the name says, update the references for this item.
Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I update the references and referrers in Link Database between these 2 items just in master database without any publishing operations? Look forward to your further reply.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check if this will do for you :).

Comment: I had tried the UpdateReferences method, but it also couldn't update the link database. I found that if I press the Save button in ArticlePageItem in Sitecore CMS, the relation between ArticleItem & ArticlePageItem can be fixed, I guess it's related to the save event of sitecore item.